# Map Update method with ifAbsent in Dart

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I'd like to modify an existing item in a map, as in replace the value of an existing key with a new one, with an added clause if the key does not exist in the Map already, to simply create a new key and value pair. The Dart documentation suggests the update method for such a purpose, but I'm not quite sure about how to implement it with the optional ifAbsent() parameter, which I assume is a line of code called if the key to be updated does not exist.

```
V update(K key, V update(V value), {V ifAbsent()});
```

According to the documentation, there is an optional parameter to be taken, but it shows an error saying too many parameters, 2 expected but 3 found.

This shows no error (not yet tested, but theoretically should work):

```
userData.update(key, value);
```

This (with the added create if not exist clause) does:

```
userData.update(key, value,
  userData[key] = value;
  );
```

Any help to get the latter or equivalent to work is much appreciated! I assume I'm missing something rather obvious here...

Comment: It might be bad practice, but can't you simply add the key value pair with bracket notation rather than figurering out if the value is present or not? Example: `yourMap['key'] = 'value';`? Look at part 9 of this [link](https://dev.to/graphicbeacon/top-10-mapobject-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart--1ido)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is a named parameter, you can use it like this:

```
userData.update(
  key, 
  // You can ignore the incoming parameter if you want to always update the value even if it is already in the map
  (existingValue) => value, 
  ifAbsent: () => value,
);
```

Comment: how to do the same thing with multiple keys and values? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Use a for loop ;)